# PG_Depend Column Alias (view) to Source Column (table) mapping dependancy

Tags: postgresql, metadata, catalog, information-schema, postgresql-8.2

I'm using version 8.2 Postresql

Have been trying to do this for days now, and I keep hitting the same wall. How to Display the following:

Source Table || Source_column || Target View || Target Column

Stg_table1||     customerid   ||     vw_customer  ||  Customer_details_id

The biggest problem I have is that I can't link the Alias names in the view, back to the Source_column. This is because the Ordinal position of the columns in the Source_table, is different to the columns in the Target_view.

I have tried using these scripts, with no luck (this joins the columns back on using information schema, and Ordinal Position)

```
    select distinct 
a.attname AS SOURCE
, a.attname::information_schema.sql_identifier AS column_name
--,  format_type(a.atttypid, NULL)  AS Source_Type
, d.refobjid::regclass AS Source_table 
, r.ev_class::regclass AS Target_View
--, pt.Typname AS TYPE, a.*
--, c.Column_name AS Target
--, c.Data_type
from pg_attribute as a
join pg_depend as d on d.refobjid = a.attrelid and d.refobjsubid = a.attnum
join pg_rewrite as r on d.objid = r.oid
--join information_schema.columns c ON a.attnum = c.ordinal_position --and r.ev_class::regclass = c.table_schema||'.'||c.table_name
--join pg_type as pt on a.atttypid = pt.oid
JOIN pg_class 
ON pg_class.oid = a.attrelid 
   AND a.attnum > 0
where
r.ev_class = 'abc.vw_customer'::regclass
and c.table_schema||'.'||c.table_name = 'vw_customer';
```

And I have also tried it this way:

```
SELECT distinct dependent.relname, pg_attribute.attname
, pg_attrdef.*
--, pg_attribute.attname::information_schema.sql_identifier AS column_name
--, pg_depend.objid, pg_attribute.*
FROM pg_depend 
JOIN pg_rewrite ON pg_depend.objid = pg_rewrite.oid 
JOIN pg_class as dependee ON pg_rewrite.ev_class = dependee.oid 
JOIN pg_class as dependent ON pg_depend.refobjid = dependent.oid 
JOIN pg_attribute ON pg_depend.refobjid = pg_attribute.attrelid 
    --AND pg_depend.refobjsubid = pg_attribute.attnum 
LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef ON pg_attribute.attrelid = pg_attrdef.adrelid AND pg_attribute.attnum = pg_attrdef.adnum   
WHERE dependee.relname = 'vw_customer'
--and attname in ('Customer_details_id', 'customerid')
AND pg_attribute.attnum > 0
```

Comment: "I'm using version 8.2 Postresql". Um. So, extremely outdated and no longer supported then. Why haven't you updated? (I usually just skip over questions for very old versions since it's too much hassle trying to deal with missing features etc).

Comment: Hi Craig, unfortunately it's not my decision. If you have a way to do this, very interested in hearing / seeing it.